# panic: proto: 'message User' is already registered

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

Even though In all the different .proto files wherever 'Message User' is being used we have a different package name but still getting this panic.
Can anyone tell me what wrong am I doing?

Comment: is the problem coming from the .proto parser, or is this afterwards, in the generated code? do you have any example of things that are conflicting? because *in principal* this should work (since you mention different package names) - a concrete example would really help. BTW: if these `User` types are all the same, you should probably use an `import` rather than declaring it lots of times.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the input. I have resolved this issue by simply replacing option go_package with package <PACKAGE_NAME>